# Cross-Domain issues on mobile Safari on iPhone, iPod & iPad

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, cross-domain, mobile-safari

I have a chat built with node. This chat is running on port 3000 of example.com. I am using this chat within the page of the same domain by calling it with jQuery's ajax call. So I have chat running on example.com:3000 and website that is including this chat running on example.com:80. Because different ports (even on the same domain) are already violation of the same-origin policy, I included in my node server headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*" to allow cross calls to my chat.

Because ajax loaded chat was looking for it's js/css files on example.com:80 I had to set paths to my js/css files on example.com:3000 to absolute paths. So chat is looking for it's js/css files with "http://example.com:3000/css/style.css" and "http://example.com:3000/js/client.js". This is working all well using regular browsers (Safari, Firefox, Chrome, etc.) for both, chat at it's own example.com:3000 and included within the example.com:80.

However, and this is the issue, it doesn't work on any mobile Safari (iPhone,iPod,Ipad). Main page of chat will load just fine with ajax call, but the subsequent js/css files are not loaded. I can't use relative paths as client.js  and style.css files are sitting on example.com:3000 which is cross-domain.

Is there any other place I need to place "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" setting? Or is there anything I need to do about paths? Or is there some setup within jQuery I need to do to make this work? I am out of ideas as there are no debugging tools on mobile Safari other than reporting errors. Which I am getting none.

Comment: Is there an actual request to the server being made from mobile Safari, and if so, whats the return code?

Comment: when embedded in parent page, request is made and node server returns the index page, which loads just fine, but there are no subsequent calls from mobile safari for style.css or client.js. When I look at node's console when embedded chat is loading, only index is requested. When I look at node's console when example.com:3000 is opened directly in mobile safari, index page, client.js and style.css are requested. So when I try to embed example.com:3000 into parent page, mobile safari doesn't send requests for any files example.com:3000 needs to function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I should have used iframe if I wanted embeded chat to be able to pull it's own internal files. That's what I ended up doing.